# How to get all the attributes of the product?

Tags: magento2

How to get all the attributes of the current product in the template?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
echo $product->getName();
```

So I got the name, I have the attribute "allow_same_day_delivery" how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This :-**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

    echo $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    echo $attribute->getStoreLabel();
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
    echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below code :

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
foreach($attributes as $attribute)
{
    echo $attribute->getName()."<br />";    

}
```

Comment: does not fit, I'm on the page of the "catalog_product_view" template, I need to find out what product is now showing

Comment: \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View::getProduct is a public method. why do you say you can't use it?

Comment: same method is used in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml